# Add last column in csv file

Tags: java, csv

I have csv file with separator tab and I want modify each row with value. can I got the reference for this case? I already search in google but I can't get the good reference. what is the best practice? what kind of library java to use easily for this case? for example I have csv file contains:

```
value1 value2 value3 
value4 value5 value6
value7 value8 value9
```

and I want to modify become:

```
value1 value2 value3 new_value1
value4 value5 value6 new_value2
value7 value8 value9 new_value3
```

and my csv file have around 10.000 rows. what kind of logic for effective to modify each row? thanks.

Comment: read in the file, best row by row, and write it out again with the additional column, to a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply modifying each row and adding a new column with a tab separator, you can do something similar to the following by using BufferedReader and BufferedWriter : -

```
BufferedReader br=null;
BufferedWriter bw=null;

try {
    File file = new File("csv file path");
    File newfile = new File("new output csv file path");

    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))) ;
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(newfile)));

    String line = null;

    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        String addedColumn = "\t"+"newstring";
        bw.write(line+addedColumn+System.lineSeparator());
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
} finally  {
    br.close();
    bw.close();
}
```

If your new column text is changing on every row, keep modifying this code accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks this worked but how to set the value each rows? because I try this code, the value each rows is same.. I want different value each rows.

Comment: and how to get the number of rows in csv?

Comment: Initialize a variable and append it to String addedColumn = "\t"+"newstring"+ variable; and increment it.

Comment: Also, do you want number of rows to be calculated separately or within this code?

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-csv/2.9.2) library and was quite satisfied.

One example [tutorial](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.nl/2017/03/how-to-read-and-write-csv-using-jackson.html) of how to use it is here.

Read the csv per row, add your new column and write to a new csv. Good luck!